# Can't open php file in apache 2.4 Centos 6

Tags: php, apache, centos6

I have a server that run Centos 6. Recently I upgrade the php to 7.2 using remi repo and apache 2.4 using the sclo(httpd24).

```
[user@server1 ~]$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.34 (Red Hat)
Server built:   May 28 2020 08:47:33

[user@server1 ~]$ php -v
PHP 7.2.33 (cli) (built: Aug  4 2020 10:02:54) ( NTS )
```

My issue is if i put an phpinfo() in /var/www/html, my browser didn't show anything, and if i open the source i only see the php code.

How do i connect the apache and php together?
Thanks..

Answer (score -1):

Have you made sure that inside the apache server configuration `httpd.conf` file you are correctly pointing to the php.so file??

You need to make sure the `LoadModule php7_module /path/to/the/php@7.2/version/libphp7.so` line is in your configuration. If you recently changed the PHP to 7.2 you need to modify the line so it points to the correct php version.

In my case I use the php 7.2, 7.3 and 7.4 versions for different purposes and inside my httpd.conf file i have the following lines:

```
#LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
#LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.3/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.4/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
```

As you can see each version point to a different so file, you need to find the correct one for the 7.2 version and point to it by commenting or uncommenting them depending on the php version.

Comment: LoadModule won't solve anything, if provided module relay on httpd 2.2 API, when using httpd 2.4.

Answer (score -1):

> I upgrade the php to 7.2 using remi

Package in my repository are build against base httpd version 2.2.

You still can use httpd 2.4 (from SCL), but in this case you need to use FPM

Read: [PHP Configuration Tips](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/)

BTW, as CentOS 6 is close to its end of life (in a few months), I heartily recommend you use a more recent version of CentOS (7 or 8 both have httpd 2.4 by default)

Comment: How is this related to the question asked by the PO? If you could, please explain better how does this makes the server configuration (apache) look and use for the proper php version

Comment: It is related to question, as related to package installed from my repository.

Comment: And web server configuration is heavily explained, step by step in linked article.